# Clarification regarding default return type at global space

Tags: c

While making a function `atof`, I splitted the entire work into two separate translational units:

---

**m.c**

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  extern  fun(char[]);  //return type not mentioned on purpose


  int main()
  {
     printf("%d\n",fun("+123.980")); //%f would also display 0.000000
     return 0;
  }
```

---

**n.c**

```
   #include<ctype.h>

   float fun(char c[])
   {
       float val=0, pow=1;
       int i;
       int sign;

       for(i=0;isspace(c[i]);i++); //SKIPPING WHITESPACE IF ANY

       if(c[i]=='+')
           sign = 1;
       if(c[i]=='-')
           sign =-1;
       ++i;

       for(;c[i]!='.';i++)
           val = val*10 + (c[i]-'0');
       ++i;

       while(isdigit(c[i]))
       {
            val = val*10 + (c[i]-'0');
            pow=pow*10;
            ++i;
       }

       return sign*val/pow;   
   }
```

The warning says that the type of function will default to `int` in this case since every variable/function type at global space without any return type mentioned explicitly defaults to int.

I was expecting the output to be `int` version of **+123.980** i.e **123** only.
But instead it shows 0 (otherwise function works fine). Why?

Comment: It's undefined behavior if the declared type doesn't match the type of the definition.

Comment: That the return type is implicitly taken as `int` does not mean that you can expect your `float` to be *converted* to `int`.  It means that the caller will assume that it already *is* an `int`.  When that's not actually the case, the language does not specify what happens.

Comment: The fact that it defaulted to the type doesn't matter. The same thing would happen if you put the `int` return type explicitly. It still doesn't match the actual type that the function returns, so it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Moreover, modern C no longer has implicit typing at any level.  Compilkers that accept it do so only for backwards compatibility.  Do not write code that relies on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implicit `int` and implicit function declarations are **removed** from the C language. They are no more. The program is **ill-formed**. If your compiler accepts it, then you are dealing with a vendor extension — or a compiler for an outdated version of C.

Before these things were removed, the program had **undefined behaviour**. All editions of the standard require that all declarations of an entity in a program must be compatible, regardless of whether anything in them is implicit or not. Violations of this rule lead to undefined behaviour, with no diagnostic required.

Comment: I am not aware of _any_ compiler that doesn't accept implicit `int` and implicit function declarations, even in the mode that is allegedly strictly conforming to the latest version of the C standard. (There may be an option to error out specifically on these constructs, but it's usually documented as making a warning into an error.) As such I think it is too harsh to describe these features as "removed from the C language", even though you are correct per the letter of the standard.

Comment: @zwol [You'd be surprised](https://godbolt.org/z/2WQ1YA), and -pedantic-errors means exactly that, error out on actual violations of the standard. Not turn all warning to errors, not turn one specific warning to an error, but *diagnose errors as errors*.

Comment: Argh, no, not this misconception again.  `-pedantic-errors` is just an older name for `-Werror=pedantic`, i.e. turn the warnings about constructs forbidden by the C standard, where the GCC developers in the early 1990s thought forbidding them was silly, into errors.  GCC's strictly conforming mode is documented to be `-std=cXX -Wall -Wpedantic`, don't confuse people by contradicting the manual on this point.

Comment: @zwol "Argh, no, not this misconception again. -pedantic-errors is just an older name for -Werror=pedantic" No it is not. The GCC manual says that very clearly, I quote, **This is not equivalent to -Werror=pedantic**.

Comment: That is a bug. Weird that they chose to document the bug rather than fixing it.

Comment: @zwol I have no idea why you are calling a useful feature "a bug".

Comment: The bug is that `-pedantic-errors` and `-(W)pedantic` enable different sets of diagnostics. There is no way to make that make sense to people who just want to use the dang thing and don't want to memorize the C standard first. The Right Thing would be individual -W switches for each diagnostic that could be turned on or off in the first place, and then reevaluate which diagnostics ought to be included in `-Wpedantic`, `-Wall`, or on by default, and make `-pedantic-errors` genuinely just a backward compatibility name for `-Werror=pedantic`. I'd have done this years ago if I still worked on GCC.

Comment: @zwol -pedantic-errors does the right thing for me. I don't really care that other non-equivalent options are out there, and I also don't care how the option is spelled. If you think the set of diagnostics emitted by by -Werror=pedantic should be changed to match that of -pedantic-errors, go ahead, more power to you, I may switch to the more consistent spelling. If you thing the other way around, then please no.